# how to reverse sorting a json?

Tags: json, python-3.x

How to reverse sort this json_1

```
json_1 = {"2019-03-27": {"student": "Amir", "Age": 10}, "2019-03-28": {"student": "Amir", "Age": 11}}
```

based on the string date to become like below:

```
{"2019-03-28": {"student": "Amir", "Age": 11}, "2019-03-27": {"student": "Amir", "Age": 10}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

using this method:

```
temp = dict(sorted(json_1.items(), key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True))

print(temp)
```

answer:
{"2019-03-28": {"student": "Amir", "Age": 11}, "2019-03-27": {"student": "Amir", "Age": 10}}